# Sending messages from pc via mobile phone using java

Tags: java, mobile

I am working on an application, using java, that has the following features:

- User connects his mobile to a PC using a usb cable or bluetooth.
- User types a message on his PC (in the textfield provided by my software).
- User types a phone number (in a textbox provided by my software).
- User clicks the send button.

Then, the software should send the message to the specified phone number and appropriate charges should be applied to my mobile balance. In other words, I am directing my mobile through my software to send message to a specified number.

How shall i do that? Is core java sufficient for this purpose or i have to use j2me or is there any particular java framework that would be suitable for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to connect the phone to the pc using serial link (COM). Need to configure the phone connected physically by USB or Bluetooth in order to appear in a COM (serial) port.

Then you need to create an application for PC (Java or whatever can open serial ports) that opens the COM port used by the phone and send the proper AT commands. Serial port can be opened by [JavaComm 2.0 Win32](http://wind.lcs.mit.edu/download/java/javacomm20-win32.zip) or more recently [RxTx](http://www.jcontrol.org/download/rxtx_en.html).

Open the serial port and write and read command by writing and reading bytes, in the same way a socket.

Then create a visual application that let user set the information like phone number for destination, text...

You need Java SE or whatever language allows you to create visual applications and opening serial ports (Java, .NET, Python...).

Some links about AT commands by serial port in Windows: [1](http://www.developershome.com/sms/howToUseHyperTerminal.asp), [2](http://www.developershome.com/sms/howToSendSMSFromPC.asp), [3](http://www.control.com.sg/at_commands_sms.aspx).

Another option could be using native API from the mobile OS through a socket, but seems complex and using AT commands and serial port should work for all phones and the only *problem* is connecting the phone by serial over USB or BlueTooth and managing the serial port.

Answer (score 0):

This is highly dependent on the Mobile OS you're using. Are you using Windows Mobile, Android OS, BlackBerry OS?

If you're using Android, then you should use the built in [`SmsManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) to do that. The `SmsManager` can do the following:

> Manages SMS operations such as sending data, text, and pdu SMS messages.

### Update:

Since you're using Symbian OS, then check out the [documentation for more information on sending SMS messages](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/SMS). I assume that you can figure out the rest (i.e. how to get the text fields for the number and the message, etc.)

Here is an example from the Symbian OS documentation:

```
public boolean sendSms(String number, String message){
    boolean result = true;
    try {
      //sets address to send message
      String addr = "sms://"+number;
      // opens connection
      MessageConnection conn = (MessageConnection) Connector.open(addr);
      // prepares text message
      TextMessage msg =
      (TextMessage)conn.newMessage(MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE);
      //set text
      msg.setPayloadText(message);
      // send message
      conn.send(msg);
      conn.close();
    } catch (SecurityException se) {
        // probably the user has not allowed to send sms
        // you may want to handle this differently
        result = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

The above snippet came from the guide on ["How to Send Text SMS in Java ME"](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_Send_Text_SMS_in_Java_ME)

Comment: I am using nokia(symbian OS/ java OS) mobile phone. I need application like [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Send_and_Read_SMS.aspx) ...but its in vb.net...i want to develop the same in java.

Comment: Seems to be an application executed in the mobile phone, not in the pc as requested.

Comment: @David Oliván Ubieto, the actual sending of the SMS will have to be executed in the mobile phone, not in the PC. Otherwise, it will be **VERY** difficult to charge the mobile account.

Comment: @Lirik Using AT commands is an option. One question to solve with your approach is how to communicate the pc with the phone applications that sends the SMS.